# How to add accessibilityLabel to a react native app (Android), so content-desc will not be empty

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native development and I am currently working on Android. I am trying to add content-desc to our app, therefore automation can use it later on. 
[image]

I did some research before, they say something about adding accessibitlityLabel and it shows up as content-desc. So I added the following code to component and the screen JavaScript file:

```
    accessible: true,
    accessibilityLabel: 'Click'
```

The ideal situation is to show "click" on a button. However, I did not see anything after I made the change. The content-desc is still empty and the button is like this:

[image]

I am trying to describe the situation clearly but this is the first time I ask a question here. So please let me know if you know how to solve the problem or you need more information from me. I will update immediately.

Thanks

Comment: have you find any feasible solution?

Answer (score 1):

While this answer may be a bit late, for those who may have similar issues in the future, you need to provide both the accessibilityLabel and testID for each component in order to see the content-desc according to this [link](https://appiumpro.com/editions/76) and that [link](https://www.headspin.io/blog/testing-react-native-apps-with-appium).

Comment: You can use like this 
export const getAccessibilityOpts = label => (Platform.OS === platformOS.android
  ? { accessible: true, accessibilityLabel: label }
  : { accessible: true, testID: label });